# Why doesn't the UICollectionViewFlowLayout work well?

Tags: ios, swift5, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I would like to use FlowLayout to show two Items in one line by using the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCV()
    }

func setupCV()
    {
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        let width = (view.frame.size.width - 10) / 2
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + 80 )
    }
```

However, when I run the project, it shows me like that:
[image]

When I debug it, the return value of the width is correct.
 [image]

The Size setting of the collection view is also correct I think:
[image]

I also try to put the layout setting part in this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {}
```

However, Xcode doesn't even excute this function.

Any Idea of what happened and how can I fix this issue? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the layout back to `collectionView`:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width + 80)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why doesn't my code work? I have downcasted it to UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: You weren't changing the `itemSize` of the collectionView as I did. Instead you were changing `itemSize` of a variable. Which was never used.